# Is it possible to activate gzip support in Matlab's webread?

Tags: matlab, gzip

I have sniffed what `webread` sends over Internet and found that it doesn't use any gzip headers. This makes transferring of big JSON and CSV files impossible.

Can I activate gzip support somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [webread](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html) it is possible to specify additional HTTP headers with [weboptions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weboptions.html).

The syntax for an additional header:

```
options = weboptions('KeyName','Name','KeyValue','Value')
```

Where *Name* and *Value* are the name of the header and its value respectively.
To enable **gzip**, you must specify the required HTTP header.

```
options = weboptions('KeyName','Accept-Encoding','KeyValue','gzip')
```

You can then use the options to perform your request.

```
data = webread(url,options)
```