# using windows system command line to run url in matlab

Tags: matlab, curl, system

How can i run curl with MATLAB in windows 8.1.
the following code does not work:

```
system(curl(url))
```

if i must use "https://" or "www." in the beginning of the url? I don'e know what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The Matlab `system` function requires the command you want to execute as a string: `system('command')`, see `help system`. The way you write it, it would execute the Matlab `curl` function, which is a vector operator, instead of the operating system function.

Also, the curl syntax is wrong, it should be `curl url`. So it would look like this: `system('curl url')`, where you replace url with the text of your URL. If you want `url` to be a variable, you could use `url = 'http://www.google.com'; system(sprintf('curl %s',url))`.

And then of course you would need to make sure that there is a working `curl` on your system.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Lukas, when you write `system(curl(url))` you are actually calling the [curl](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/curl.html) Matlab function.

The correct syntax for executing a `curl` request with Matlab:

```
command = 'curl http://www.google.com';
response = system(command);
```

`response` will contain the request response. You may specify any additional flags for your request in the command character vector. To execute system command successfully, you must have `curl` included in your path. To confirm this, open a terminal and type `curl`.

Note that since Matlab 2014b you can execute GET and POST requests with [webread](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html), and  since Matlab 2015b you can execute POST requests with [webwrite](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html). You can use [weboptions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weboptions.html) to specify additional parameters for the request, including additional headers as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50467023/3390419) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50468904/3390419).